# Rubymine - Uncaught exception: Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubymine

I am getting a "Rubymine - Uncaught exception: Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources" error, however, when I start the server in the console using the `rails s` command, it starts properly. I don't know what went wrong, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use the same Ruby installation with the same set of installed gems in the console and in RubyMine? Verify in `Tools` | `Show Gem Environment`. Also check that your `Gemfile` lists the correct take version and `bundle install` works without problems with the Ruby interpreter selected in RubyMine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

this works for me